# Get data whether the id is there or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `SubDivision` which holds a

- SubDivisionID
- SubDivisionName
- Directions

Then I have a table called `CustomerSubDivisionXREF` which holds this

- CustomerSubDivisionXREFID
- SubDivisionID
- CustomerID

My stored procedure looks like this

```
select
    sub.SubDivisionID,
    sub.SubDivisionName,
    csxref.SubDivisionID as "Assigned"
from [SubDivision] sub
    left join [CustomerSubDivisionXREF] csxref on csxref.SubDivisionID = sub.SubDivisionID
```

This returns all the `SubDivisions` and null for the Assigned, which is fine, and looks like this..

[image: What is returned]

However, once I introduce the

```
where csxref.CustomerID = 9
```

Then nothing gets returned, and I understand why. But the question is, how do I get all the SubDivisions, regardless if there is any assigned to a customer? So I guess in short I would like to pass a CustomerID and if there is no SubDivisions assigned to that CustomerID then I would like it to still return what I show in the picture.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I have to pass a CustomerID into this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use a subquery:

```
SELECT sub.SubDivisionID, sub.SubDivisionName, csxref.SubDivisionID AS Assigned
FROM SubDivision AS sub
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.SubDivision 
    FROM CustomerSubDivisionXREF AS t 
    WHERE t.CustomerID = 9
) AS csxref ON sub.SubDivisionID = cxsref.SubDivisionID
```

To me this tends to be a bit more readable than the multi-predicate `on` clause as you can clearly see that only the subquery's records are the ones restricted, though I'm unsure if one performs better than the other out of the box.

Comment: I tried your way and changed the t.SubDivision to t.SubDivisionID because it was throwing an error and when I run it I get the error
The multi-part identifier "cxsref.SubDivisionID" could not be bound.

Comment: Actually this worked, there was a typo in your answer
AS csxref ON sub.SubDivisionID = cxsref.SubDivisionID, should be
AS csxref ON sub.SubDivisionID = csxref.SubDivisionID

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that condition in the `on` clause:

```
select sub.SubDivisionID, sub.SubDivisionName,
       csxref.SubDivisionID as "Assigned"
from [SubDivision] sub left join
     [CustomerSubDivisionXREF] csxref
     on csxref.SubDivisionID = sub.SubDivisionID and
        csxref.CustomerID = 9;
```

By putting it in the `where` clause, you are turning the join into an `inner join` -- because non-matching rows get `NULL` and that fails the comparison.

Comment: There's one thing that I forgot to mention, I have to pass an CustomerID into this stored procedure